# Update in LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Is there any possibility to make update in the database by using LINQ only without using LINQ to SQL? If yes, please provide an example.

What is different between LINQ and LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "Just"  LINQ (LINQ-to-Objects) won't update anything.

So to update a database you need either LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities (Entity Framework).

But you will need something like that to read from the database too, so there should be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is just framework support for powerful data querying in the .NET language.  For any support, you need a LINQ provider.  Some providers:

1. LINQ to Objects -> Using LINQ to query in memory collections
2. LINQ to SQL -> Light weight data query provider for SQL Server.
3. LINQ to Entities -> ORM for querying multiple databases.
4. LINQ to XML -> or XLINQ for querying XML

Comment: LINQ isn't really a "framework". However, I didn't think a -1 was justified so...